# c++ MFC and handling windows Messages

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-messages, message-map

What code is needed in the message map for Windows messages?

The code calling the function:

```
SendMessage(GRID_WM_UPDATECELL,(WPARAM)1,(LPARAM)&sDisp);
```

The function:

```
LRESULT CNJAGridCtrl::OnUpdateCell(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
}
```

Comment: How does the declaration of OnUpdateCell look like? How does the message map entry look like?

Comment: It is not caused by the casts.  You get this diagnostic when a function declaration doesn't match the function implementation.  You gave us no hint at all what function that might be.  The debugger tells you.

Comment: @WernerHenze I added the declaration afx_msg LRESULT OnUpdateCell(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM, lParam); but I also have  LRESULT OnUpdateCell(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); and virtual void UpdateCell(BOOL bAdd, NJACELLINFO sDisp); in the header file. Is this correct?

Comment: Use the Call Stack debugger window.  It is the function call before the statement where it stopped that is borken.  Could be buried inside a macro, MFC likes them too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message map line should be

```
ON_MESSAGE(GRID_WM_UPDATECELL, OnUpdateCell)
```

and the function signature should be

```
LRESULT CNJAGridCtrl::OnUpdateCell(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

Comment: What are you talking about? There is no virtual function here.

Comment: Instead of using afx_msg the code is using virtual functions and I'm wondering if that might be part of the problem. It might also be something similar to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179534/message-map-mfc-with-multiple-inheritance-how-to-avoid-warning-c4407-and-runtim)